# Duplicate jhipster project

Tags: jhipster

I have developped a Jhipster project.
I need to create a new one which will be quite the same (but not the same).   I would like to duplicate the first project. 
The second project would just have a different name and different main package name.

Is there a way to do that properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. Duplicate your project folder, in new folder edit `.yo-rc.json` file and change name and package. You may also want to change the rememberMeKey
2. Delete src folder
3. Run `jhipster --with-entities` to re-generate app with new settings
4. Copy back from old project what you've added

Comment: Thanks, actually I don't want to loose the service and controllers created in the first project. Deleting src would make me loose them.

Comment: That's not a big issue copy them back and refactor them to change their package.

Comment: Otherwise proceed as you would do for any other project, use your IDE to repackage, as long as you don't change entity names you should be fine.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. Now is the time to duplicate the project. Just to know if there have been faster solutions since I created this post... Otherwise I ll go with your proposal!

Comment: Thanks, actually just by refactoring the packages' name did it.

Comment: Thanks Gael. Is It the same in 2019?

Comment: It still works in 2019 though there is an alternative if you created your app using JDL, in which case you can edit JDL file and re-generate new app from it, see https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#applicationdeclaration

Answer (score 0):

Delete yo-rc.json .... and generate your new entity then every thing will be ok (Tested)