# How to change rememberMeKey?

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to follow instructions to create a duplicate project following this question: [Duplicate jhipster project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762573/duplicate-jhipster-project) Supposing that it still applies!

And I do not know how to change the rememberMeKey in Jhipster?

Comment: Have you tried removing it from `.yo-rc.json` file and re-generating?

Comment: Yes, thanks, the question is how do I change the rememberMeKey in Jhipster?

Comment: So when you removed it, did the re-generation create a new value in .yo-rc.json?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one-liner in your project folder to run the exact method that the generator uses:

```
node -p 'require("generator-jhipster/generators/utils.js").getRandomHex()'
```